# Cisco interface controller counter "Valid frames, too small"

Tags: switch, counters, drops

I have a Cisco 3560 switch which is dropping some frames
the frames that are dropped are seen in a SPAN session for the ingress port (monitor source) but not in a SPAN session for the egress
It has a positive counter displayed with show controllers "Valid frames, too small" against the receive side of the ingress port.

I cannot yet find any Cisco references to define this value. The frames that are being dropped have a Wireshark-reported frame length of 214 octets.

Does anybody know of a reference where this value is defined? (or know what this value refers to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12-2_55_se/command/reference/3560_cr/cli2.html#wp1917706) I can see:

The number of frames received on an interface that are smaller than 64 bytes (or 68 bytes for VLAN-tagged frames) and that have valid FCS values. The frame size includes the FCS bits but excludes the frame header bits.

Now, why this should show up for 214-bytes frames is hard to say. Is it possible that the frames matching against this counter are not the same ones you see on wireshark?

Comment: Thanks for that, I wonder is this the same as a runt, I always assumed a runt would have an invalid FCS.  It is certainly possible that the frames matching this are not the ones I see in Wireshark.  Either way I guess, the switch is duff. Either it's mis-reporting and dropping or it's dropping silently.

Comment: Runts are basically 'debris' from collisions. Those won't have a valid FCS. Maybe you have some bad equipment connected to this 3560, which is (for example) "forgetting" to pad small packets up to 64 bytes